# BNF grammar that generates language L

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, bnf, formal-languages

I spend a lot of time but still can't understand how to solve this. I have the answer. Can you tell me how he come up with it?

Is there a specific rules or standard construct I can follow? I know the rules for union and concatenation but not when it's reversed.

[image: BNF grammar with no ambiguity]

[image: This is the solution, but I don't understand how he comes up with it. Is there a specific rules I can follow when writing such grammar?]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `x` is a (possibly improper) substring of `y`, then `x^r c y` can be written as `x^R c wxz` where `w` and `z` are arbitrary strings over `(a+b)*`.

Now we can try to "slice" the strings in this language to see how they can be generated by CFGs. The non-regular part of this is making sure that `x^R` and `x` come out right; the rest is trivial. So we need some rules like:

```
S -> aXa | bYb | c
```

This gives us `x^R c x`. We are missing the `w` and the `z`. The `w` we can add by letting any arbitrary string come after `c`:

```
S -> aSa | bSb | cA
A -> aA | bA | e
```

The `z` we can get by changing `S` to `T` and adding a new `S` that produces `T` followed by anything:

```
S -> TA
T -> aTa | bTb | cA
A -> aA | bA | e
```

All we neglected to ensure was that `|x| > 1`. We do that by changing `T -> cA` to two productions `T -> acAa | bcAb`. This yields the suggested grammar (Not the only right one, just one grammar that works) and explains how we got there.

Comment: why not T->acaA | bcAb?

Comment: I think with T->acAa | bcAb. The string "acab" will faill.

Comment: @ZacUwyoH It needs to be acAa | bcAb because the A here lets you generate an arbitrary w. Recall that strings in your language can be written x^R c w x z. We need to allow any w in there. acab does not fail and is generated by S -> TA -> TbA -> Tb -> acAab -> acab.